# Using Postgres COPY TO for data export without overwriting file

Tags: postgresql, export, psql

I'm running several queries with a script and psql. I am also exporting the results to a.csv using the COPY TO command. However, this overwrites the file a.csv when I would like to instead append the results to a.csv instead.

Is it possible using the COPY TO syntax perhaps there is some parameter I am missing? Or should I look at using other tools?

Answer (score 9):

You could use the meta command [`\copy` in psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) (which encapsulates SQL `COPY`) **on the command line**, send it to `stdout` and and redirect output to be *appended* to a file - with `>>` instead of `>`:

```
psql -c '\copy (SELECT 1, 2) to stdout' >> /path/to/file_to_append_to.csv
```

(You probably need more connection parameters.)
You can use SQL `COPY` as well:

```
psql -c 'COPY (SELECT 1, 2) TO STDOUT' >> /path/to/file_to_append_to.csv
```

But it's often more convenient to use `\copy` instead because ([quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html#AEN77698)):

> file accessibility and access rights depend on the client rather than
>   the server when `\copy` is used.

**Or**, like [Abelisto commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167075/using-postgres-copy-to-for-data-export-without-overwriting-file/167076#comment322957_167076), from **inside psql** or any other client - if the program `cat` is available (basically on all *nix OS):

```
COPY (SELECT 1, 2) TO PROGRAM 'cat >> /path/to/file_to_append_to.csv'
```

**Or**, still from **inside psql**, on *any* system, you can set the current directory and an output file with:

```
\cd /path/to/
\o file_to_append_to.csv
```

The file gets created (only) if it does not exist yet.
Then you can also SQL `COPY` (or still `\copy` as well):

```
COPY (SELECT 1, 2) TO STDOUT;
```

The output is *appended* to the file.

Comment: Or, for example, `copy ... to program 'cat >> file.csv'`

Comment: I have been tryinig both \copy and COPY ... to program 'C:\cat.exe >> C:\...\file.csv'. This works in psql terminal but when I am passing this to psql through a .sh script, the copy fails: COPY fails with "DETAIL:  child process was terminated by exception 0xC0000135" and \copy replaces PROGRAM with STDOUT and complains of a syntax error in the proceeding ' i.e. "...TO STDOUT 'C:\...". What could be going on?

Answer (score 2):

## Exporting multiple queries to the same file using `UNION` and `COPY`

Just use `COPY TO` and a query.

```
COPY { table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ] | ( query ) }
    TO { 'filename' | PROGRAM 'command' | STDOUT }
    [ [ WITH ] ( option [, ...] ) ]
```

So something like this

```
COPY (
  SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,10) AS t(x)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM generate_series(10,20) AS t(x)
) TO '/tmp/foo.csv' CSV;
```