# Can we copy data from 1 text file to 2 postgresql tables?

Tags: postgresql, copy

I have a text file with some data and I have two similar tables in my postgresql database. Is it possible to copy a part of the data present in the file, say first 10 lines, to the first table and the remaining in the second table?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The SQL `COPY` command itself has no provision for that. But you can specify `PROGRAM` as input. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.5)

> When `PROGRAM` is specified, the server executes the given command and
>   reads from the standard output of the program, or writes to the
>   standard input of the program. The command must be specified from the
>   viewpoint of the server, and be executable by the PostgreSQL user.

Then, assuming you are on a Linux system, you can `COPY` the first 10 lines with:

```
COPY tbl1 FROM PROGRAM 'head -n10 /path/to/file/my.csv';
```

To `COPY` the rest, starting with line 11:

```
COPY tbl2 FROM PROGRAM 'sed -n 11,\$p /path/to/file/my.csv';
```

Or, to `COPY` without comments with leading `#` / only comments (asked in comment):

```
COPY tbl3 FROM PROGRAM 'awk ''!/^#/'' /path/to/file/my.csv';
COPY tbl4 FROM PROGRAM 'awk ''/#/ { sub(/^#/, ""); print }'' /path/to/file/my.csv';
```

The last command removes the leading `#` from comments (but not additional whitespace).

Consult the `man` page or your preferred online source about the shell commands `head`, `sed` and `awk` ...

As always, you need the necessary privileges. Consider the psql meta command `\copy` if you are not superuser nor member of the `pg_execute_server_program` role.

Related:

- [Using Postgres COPY TO for data export without overwriting file](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167075/using-postgres-copy-to-for-data-export-without-overwriting-file/167076#167076)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Erwin. One more thing, suppose after every few rows of data in my file, there are comments(starting with #), is it then possible to store those comments in another table and the rows of data in another?

Comment: @suvrat: I added more above to address comments.